# @types not recognized on compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, types

This might be pretty dumb, but I can't manage to use the `@types` in the `node_modules` folder correctly.

From what I understand, I need to simply configure my `tsconfig.json` file to make it work correctly as follow :

```
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
],
```

For instance, I have in the `@types` the `fullcalendar` definition containing the following :

```
export as namespace FC;

export interface Calendar {
    /**
     * Gets the version of Fullcalendar
     */
    version: string;
}
```

I want to use this definition from my angular component :

```
foo: FC.Calendar;
```

which is recognized correctly, and I can get to the definition without any issue. (that would be because the binding with the `tsconfig.json` is made correctly I believe), but at the compilation time, `angular-cli` only tells me :

> Cannot find namespace 'FC'.

Am I missing a webpack configuration somwhere to make this work ? Do I have a specific `import` to make to make this work ?

Comment: No, you don't need to do **anything** to use `node_modules/@types`, as it states in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types): `By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation`. How are you importing `FC`?

Comment: Well, I am not importing anything at the moment, but I don't even know how to import it correctly

Comment: The compiler can't find `FC.Calendar` because you're not importing it (or referencing it). I suggest that you read [Namespaces and Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) and then also go into the page for Modules and the one for Namespaces.

Comment: Okay, I managed to make it work by using : `import * as FC from '@types/fullcalendar';` It does compile now.

Comment: No, you don't need to specify the path to it. The idea is that the import is there for runtime as well, not just for compilation. So it should be: `import * as FC from 'fullcalendar';`

Comment: Good point, it works as expected. Nice !

Comment: You could also do `declare let FC: any;` and then you can access any properties on `FC` within your code without the TS compiler yelling at you. This assumes that `FC` will be available as a global variable on page load.